# svn keeping feature branch up to date without closing branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branch

I have a main branch on which I'm working on which is `branch_1`. I opened a feature `branch_feature` on which I'm working on too. 
I made some changes on `branch_1` and need to merge them in the `branch_feature`. 
Is it possible to do this in `svn` without closing the merged branch?

Comment: What do you mean by "closing"?

Comment: when I merge two branch in webstorm, it does close the branch I'm merging changes from